# Java SDK v3: Gone exception with direct connection mode

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

Note that I am using the new `azure-cosmos` - dependency (v3).

Here's some of my code:

```
    // Somewhere in my configuration class
    @Bean
    public FeedOptions feedOptions() {
        return new FeedOptions()
            .enableCrossPartitionQuery(true)
            .maxItemCount(cosmosdbThrottleRetryAttempts)
            .maxDegreeOfParallelism(1);
    }

    @Bean
    public CosmosClient cosmosClient() throws Exception {

        final RetryOptions retryOptions = new RetryOptions()
            .maxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests(cosmosdbThrottleRetryAttempts)
            .maxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds(cosmosdbThrottleRetryWaitTimeSeconds)
            ;

        final ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy()
            .retryOptions(retryOptions)
            .connectionMode(ConnectionMode.DIRECT)
            .maxPoolSize(1000)
            .requestTimeoutInMillis(operationTimeoutSeconds * 1000)
            ;

        return CosmosClient.builder()
            .endpoint(cosmosdbEndpoint)
            .resourceToken(loadKey(cosmosdbKey))
            .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.EVENTUAL)
            .connectionPolicy(connectionPolicy)
            .build()
            ;
    }

    // Then somewhere in my service:

   ...

   documentClient
        .createDatabaseIfNotExists(databaseName)
        .flatMap(db -> db.database()
            .createContainerIfNotExists(collectionName, "/partitionKey")
        )
        .map(CosmosContainerResponse::container)
        .flatMapMany(c -> c
            .queryItems(query, feedOptions)
        )
        .flatMapIterable(FeedResponse::results)
        ...
```

My service works as expected when using `ConnectionMode.GATEWAY`, but when I change to `ConnectionMode.DIRECT` (which is suposed to improve performance) I get the following warnings when running a query:

```
WARN [CosmosEventLoop-2-2] GoneAndRetryWithRetryPolicy: Received gone exception, will retry, GoneException{error=null, resourceAddress='null', statusCode=410, message=The requested resource is no longer available at the server., causeInfo=null, responseHeaders={}, requestHeaders=null}
WARN [CosmosEventLoop-2-2] GoneAndRetryWithRetryPolicy: Received gone exception after backoff/retry. Will fail the request. GoneException{error=null, resourceAddress='null', statusCode=410, message=The requested resource is no longer available at the server., causeInfo=null, responseHeaders={}, requestHeaders=null}
```

Then, the application just hangs (tested for up to 5 minutes).
The documentation of Cosmos DB does not have any mention of `410 GONE` - exceptions. What could this mean?

Comment: Those seem internal logs, do your requests get a 410?

Comment: @Matias Quaranta I don't get any response, just a timeout that I defined myself after ~5 minutes.

Comment: Does it happen on all operations? If not, could you share the snippet of that operation? If it happens on all operations, and since you are using Direct, is it running within a corporate network that might be blocking [Direct's port range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips#networking)?

Comment: So while I was testing it happened when querying documents. Interesting side note: I migrated back to `azure-cosmosdb` 2.4.4 and direct connect works but sometimes warns with the same warning, while still seemingly working...

Comment: @MarkusAppel So, you mean the same code works for `2.4.4` version?

Comment: @JayGong No of course not. But the same logic implemented using the `2.4.4` SDK behaves differently.